# AngularJS Directive: link objects in collection with transclude/compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

One of my pages needs to load an SVG file then edit it. Right now it is a huge directive that handles both the SVG as a whole, as well as every interaction tied to the shapes. I would like to split it up, so that I can put the interactions for the shapes into separate directives.

Here's what I do right now:

```
<svg-canvas 
    fills="fills"
    src="{{svgImageUrl}} 
    selected-shape="selectedShape"
    on-drop-fill="addFill(pathId, fill)"
/>
```

The directive is managing both the parent (the SVG) and the interactions for every single child shape. For example, I add a click handler to every shape, and update the selected-shape on the scope. I deep watch changes to fills, look up the correct shape and apply it.

I would rather do something like this:

```
<svg-canvas src="{{svgImageUrl}}>
    <svg-each-shape as="shape" svg-click="selectShape(shape)" svg-fill="fills[shape.id]" on-drop-fill="addFill(shape, fill)"/>
</svg-canvas>
```

Conceptually, it seems much cleaner to be able to create separate directives for svg-click, svg-fill, etc. If you squint, this is a lot like ng-repeat. Ng-repeat lets you separate the interactions of the contents from the parent. The big difference is that the  directive is never supposed to go in the DOM. I just want a way to add directives to each path separately.

Is it possible to use transclusion to link an object (shape) in a collection onto a child scope so that I can work with it? Without putting it in the DOM? How?

Comment: what do you mean not put it in DOM?

Comment: There should be no <svg-each-shape/> elements on the page. The svg-canvas dumps the whole SVG contents into the page. I want to use that inner directive as a launch point for adding directives to each inner shape/path, but I'm getting those by walking the SVG dom after it is added to the page. <svg-canvas> has a reference to every shape object, but my controller doesn't. I'd like to use <svg-each-shape/> to tie the two together.

Comment: simple demo might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set `transclude: true` in the parent, and call the transclude function once for each child, with the appropriate properties set on the scope so the child directives have something to work with.

Here's a simplified example: svgCanvas.js

```
.directive('svgCanvas', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE', 
        transclude: true,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return function(scope, el, attrs) {
                return link(scope, el, attrs, transclude)
            }
        }
    }

    function link(scope, el, attrs, transclude) {
         // ... other code
         // after loaded 
         function afterLoaded() {
             el.find("rect, path").each(function() {
                 var childScope = scope.$new()
                 // child directives can read ._path to work their magic
                 childScope._path = $(this)
                 transclude(childScope, function(clone) {
                    // You don't have to do anything in here if you don't want
                    // transclude runs all child directives
                 })
             })
         }

    }
})
```

Here's an example of one of the inner directives: svgClick.js

```
.directive('svgClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var $path = scope._path
            $path.click(function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.svgClick)
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

And here is how you would use it

```
<svg-canvas src="{{svgImageUrl}}">

    <svg-each-path
        svg-click="selectPath(path.id)" 
    />

</svg-canvas>
```